# How do you combine a string and a variable in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I want to change the text of a label to:

`variable + string + variable.`

How am I suppose to do that?

```
self.yesNo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:_variable, @" is divisible by " , variable];
```

That is what what I have so far, but there are a bunch of errors. What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation states:

```
+ (instancetype)stringWithFormat:(NSString *)format
```

where `format` is

*A format string. See **Formatting String Objects** for examples of how to use this method, and **String Format Specifiers** for a list of format specifiers. This value must not be nil.*

Example:

```
NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A string: %@, a float: %1.2f", @"string", 31415.9265];
```

[|-- NSString Reference --|](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW21)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d is divisible by %d", _variable, variable];
```

Answer (score 0):

Following way to show variable with String :

```
int variable = 15
NSString *string = @"Jaspidis Z."
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@ %d",variable , string,variable]

output :  15 Jaspidis Z. 15
```